# Why use function expression in Angular ControlValueAccessor implementation?

Tags: javascript, angular, forms, controlvalueaccessor

I've noticed most implementations of `ControlValueAccessor` define their `onChange` and `onTouch` functions via function expressions, like so:

```
    private _onChange = (_: any) => { };
    private _onTouched = () => { };
```

Is there any specific reason to do it like this over regular function declaration?

Comment: Not sure, but according to https://alligator.io/angular/custom-form-control/, it make sense that you want to be able to reaffect a new function in `registerOnChange(fn: (rating: number) => void)` and `registerOnTouched(fn: () => void)`, which you can't do without function expression.

Answer (score 0):

Because it is more compact, and it preserves the `this` from where the function is **declared** instead of where the function is **executed**